# Insert into MySQL from Chrome Extension

Tags: mysql, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I like to click my chrome extension and it takes the current tabs url and inserts it into a MySQL database. It seems I have to use an xhr, however I a loose grasp of how it works.  I also slightly get the idea [Chrome Extension → Web App API → MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769081/connecting-to-db-from-a-chrome-extension).

So far I have a working chrome extension that grabs the current tabs url and displays it and a php file connecting to my database. However I could use some help getting to url variable to a Web API then to my php file.

Lastly, I am a bit of a newbie so I apologize if this is questioned poorly.

**Edit**

Here is my code and more details...

currentUrl.js

```
//grab the current url

   chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
       var tabId = tab.id;
       tabUrl = tab.url;

       document.write(tabUrl);
   });
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="currentUrl.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  </head>
</html>
```

insertdb.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","my_pw","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO urlHistory (Urls)
VALUES ('Url'");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Current Url",
  "description": "Grab tab's current url",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "url_icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
    // dont't I have to put something here?
  ]
}
```

Comment: The "Web API" you are referring to is in fact your PHP file. Does the PHP file "know" how to store a list of URLs in your DB ? If yes, the only thing you need to do is to make an AJAX call from your extension to your PHP file (i.e. to a URL at your server pointing to the PHP file) and pass the list of URLs as POST data. Give more details on what your code (extension, PHP) **can** do, so we can fill-in the gaps.

Comment: Do you have some log-in mechanism in place ? How do you plan on preventing other people accessing your DB ?

Comment: I am using this code as a learning experience and just trying to understand Ajax.

Comment: Did you try my proposed solution below ? Did it work for you ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use XHR to send the URL over to your server where `insertdb.php` will be listening for and storing URLs in the DB.

Some more info on relevant concepts:

- **[MySQLi prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)**
- **[XMLHttpRequests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)**
- **[browserAction](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/browserAction)**

---

**Sample code:**

<sub>(The code below is for demonstration only and it does not take into account basic concepts, such as input validation, user authorization/authentication, error handling etc (all of which are essential for a production-ready solution).)</sub>

**In insertdb.php:**

```
<?php
if (isSet($_POST['url'])) {
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'my_pw', 'my_db');
    ...
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, 'INSERT INTO urlHistory (Urls) VALUES (?)');
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $_POST['url']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

**In background.js:**

```
function sendCurrentUrl(url) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.addEventListener('readystatechange', function (evt) {
    if (req.readyState === 4) {
      if (req.status === 200) {
        alert('Saved !');
      } else {
        alert("ERROR: status " + req.status);
      }
    }
  });
  req.open('POST', 'https://your_domain/your/path/insertdb.php', true);
  req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  req.send('url=' + encodeURIComponent(url));
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
   sendCurrentUrl(tab.url);
});
```

**In manifest.json:**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "version": "0.0",

  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab", 
    "https://your_domain/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What do you see in the console log ? Any errors ? What XHR requests do you see in the Nerwork tab of the Debugger ? Did you replace the URLs with your exact URLs ?

Comment: I apologize, I am a newer programmer and have no experience with console logs.  I will look into them and try doing what you advise. -- as for the urls, I used the urls specific on running locally with my Apache server, so it would be http://localhost/urls/insertdb.php