# Which Database Can be Used With Chrome Extension

Tags: database, sqlite, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am  trying to create a Google Chrome Extension which Needs to store Data from users for login authentication. Can you please advise me which Database I can try to have with the app? I already tried the `SQLite` but I am not sure that end users can update the tables by inserting or deleting rows? I also saw some posts about Web Databases but didn't find any thing really useful for it! now my question is: 
1- Is SQLite capable to be updated by end users(While eht do not have SQLite on their Machine?)
2- If not, what kind of Secure database I can use instead?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

In an extension you can use webDB (apps cannot, however), indexedDB, localStorage and/or the chrome.storage api. The later has the added bonus of not being visible if an end user figures out how to inspect your extension with devtools. If you're worried about credentials being stored as plain text, you can always find a js crypto Implementation somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a repeat of the question : [Connecting to DB from a Chrome Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769081/connecting-to-db-from-a-chrome-extension).
It basically says you should use an intermediary webapp for db calls, and use AJAX to communicate between the chrome extension and that app.

Comment: Thanks for reply rogue_js, but it doesn't look like to be a good solution for my case since in my app every user have their own database.A portable data base which can be attached to app like SQLite

Comment: Have you considered just storing the data locally?  It wouldn't be particularly secure, but if each user has their own individual data it wouldn't be the end of the world.  Why exactly do you need the database?

Comment: well those data can be crucial like database administration credintial

Comment: I want to have access to do some secure things like salting or sanitizing the data