# Chrome extension accessing MDB file

Tags: javascript, ms-access, google-chrome-extension

I wish to create a chrome extention that checks a database file on our business LAN network for stock count of searched items in the online stock ordering site we use to avoid over-ordering.

So I'm thinking this sort of work-flow:

- Staff searches query on order website
- All page results get collected via chrome extention
- Database query to .MDB file on local network (\master\point-of-sale\db.mdb)
- Render the resulting counts of each item in a HTML+CSS insert on the page
- Update on page next (if needed)

I've created things with NodeJS and Angular but chrome extentions are new to me, so is MDB files so I am not sure the best approach for this problem

To add, I wont have issues with creating the grabbing of the barcodes/names or building a UI etc those are all well documented things for extentions I am just not sure how to go about querying a MDB file and getting the results to work with

Comment: Time to check the [official Getting Started](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) tutorial for chrome extensions. An [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769081/connecting-to-db-from-a-chrome-extension) about connecting to database.'

Comment: @AdiMabfalin the database post is about a MySQL on a live server, not a file that I can access via network folders

Comment: There's nothing in extensions API or JavaScript in general to query an mdb file. You can read it as a binary file and reimplement the entire query engine yourself, of course, but maybe someone already did that, try googling. That said, the usual approach is to run a server app in that remote computer that provides a web-accessible API for querying mdb files which you use from your extension via XMLHttpRequest/fetch.