# Connecting to SQL server from a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, sql-server

I have chrome extension which will only be available for people within the company I work for. currently all the data of extension is saved in google sheets. now i need to save the data in SQL server. do i need some plugin or how to do the connectivity between SQL and extension. Extension is mainly javascript.

Comment: you use a server side language and some ajax calls

Comment: This is too broad a question. Can you give some more detail, for example, your server side environment? Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create an intermediary web app that will interface with the Database. Then you can make AJAX calls from the extension to your web app's API, which will in turn query the database and return results.

Chrome Extension → Web App API → MySQL

[More info on Chrome AJAX API here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr)

A similar question like yours has been solved, check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769081/connecting-to-db-from-a-chrome-extension).