# Users can decompile Source Code, how can I safely access Databases and Servers?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, encryption, google-chrome-extension, cryptography

So, Im programming a Chrome Extension. I want to store data in a Database.
I logically dont want anyone else to have access to the database. How can I make it that I access a database/server without giving away my passwords etc. to the user?
I saw that its possible to decompile installed extensions.

Comment: Doesn't database need to store itself storage at remote server and not at LOCAL storage of user's pc?(For security reasons of course)

Comment: Yes, but I have to access the server with the extension and for this I have to put my access keys into the code, dont I?

Comment: I'm not familiar with extensions, but who has access to it? is there a way to log in to the extension?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connecting to DB from a Chrome Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769081/connecting-to-db-from-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: Anybody who installs the extension has access to full source code, this can be anybody. In the question it extra says "Its used in my company, with people who have access to the database", I dont think security is their concern.